# Application of Lebesgue ... theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following task:

Let $A$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{r^d} m^d(A \cap B_r(x))$. Does this limit exists a.e.? I do not see any application of Lebesgue point/differentation theorem...

Comment: What happens when you apply the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to the indicator function for the set $A$?

Comment: ok nice, but the open problem is, that in the denominator (after application of lebesgue diff theorem) I have $m^d(B_r(x))$ and not, as above, $r^d$...

Comment: Yes, and $m^d(B_r(x))$ is proportional to $r^d$. For example, if $d = 2$, then $m^d(B_r(x)) = \pi r^2$ (the area of a circle). If $d = 3$, then $m^d(B_r(x)) = \frac 4 3 \pi r^3$ (the volume of a sphere).

Comment: nice, perfect, thanks! and in order to determine the values outside a set of measure zero? Thats just $1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise, right?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely right.